ffmpeg in ubuntu slower than on win11
Completely new clean Ubuntu 24.04 desktop install, performance power mode, installed ffmpeg 6.1.1-3ubuntu5, installed s-tui for power monitoring. Testing video recompression with -c:v libx265 -crf 27 takes 23 minutes while s-tui reporting around 140-150W (but I don't see any throttling, all cores seem to boost to their max boost frequency according to s-tui). In windows the same recompression takes 18m26s while using almost 180W on average.
Mprime small FFTs in ubuntu fully loads the CPU up to the set power limits (230W/210W).
How do I make ffmpeg perform better?
i7-14700K, MSI pro z790-p wifi ddr4, KF436C18BBK2/64, kingston fury renegade 2TB NVMe

Are you using -threads 0 and/or -preset ultrafast?

I don't know, I'm only doing -c:v libx265 -crf 27, nothing else. I tried with -preset ultrafast and it was much much faster and using a lot of power and the resulting file size was also smaller, but I haven't noticed worse video quality that I would expect from a faster preset and lower file size. How is this possible? I also tried -preset veryslow and it used even less power. I haven't tried yet on windows.

adding -threads 0 didn't change anything, looks like it's already using the optimal number of threads

It depends on source.  If the input is already mpeg-4, -ultrafast shouldn't affect quality.  That's -crf.  It will cause noticeable change.

so -threads 0 -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -crf 25 is still faster on win11 by about 8%. s-tui on ubuntu reports cpu utilization around 74-84% The threads option doesn't seem to affect much: I tried lower numbers and got the same encoding time except when I went as low as 4 the time increased by about 1% and with 2 threads the time was 7% longer. The ffmpeg initial output still says "thread pool created using 20 threads"
